# Android 4.4 Soft Keyboard is empty

Tags: android, webview, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm trying to make my android app backwards compatible, from targetSDK=21 to minSDK=19. My app has webviews. When an input field in the webview is focused, the keyboard comes up, but nothing is displayed but the background color in place of the keyboard. But something is definitely there; when I press the space where the keyboard should be, keys are being pressed (ie. letters get entered into the input field), but I just can't see them. Also, the keyboard space covers up the webview so I know that something is there. Any ideas on what's going on?

EDIT: Here's a link to a screenshot. The bottom grayish area is where the invisible keyboard is. If I press on this area, keys do get pressed but the actual keyboard is not visible.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/4pbfj6gey2h6dyc/Screenshot_2015-09-17-12-50-22.png?dl=0